# ArrayInput validate in react-admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

Well, I'm new with react, but I'm trying to validate two dates (im using dayjs for the dates).

I want to check that a date in a field "to" doesnt come before another date in field "from".

I have the following in a file called `regex.js`:

```
    export const validateFromBeforeTo = (values) => { 
    const message = "error: date in field 'to' cant be before date in field 'from'";
    console.log((dayjs(values[0].from).diff(dayjs(values[0].to)) < 0 )? "false" : "true");
    return (dayjs(values[0].from).diff(dayjs(values[0].to)) < 0 )? undefined : message
    }
```

(I know it's not perfect since i have to loop, but for now is just to make it work)

And I have the following in the `test.js` file

```
    <FormTab label="MyForm">
   
    <CustomTitleField title="Disponibilità" />
    <ArrayInput source="availability" label="avail" validate={validateFromBeforeTo}>
        <SimpleFormIterator>
            <DateTimeInput label="Da" source="from" showTime validate={validateFifteenMin()} />
            <DateTimeInput label="A" source="to" showTime  />
        </SimpleFormIterator>
    </ArrayInput>

    </FormTab>
```

My problem is that if I `console.log` the result, when i change the dates it prints correctly, but it does NOT shows errors in the form.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you coould provide us with the source of the whole form to be sure something is not wrong on root level

Comment: @KiaKaha well there's only a form tag but anyway I updated the block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the ArrayInput does not handle error on itself but on its childs. But you could made a better generic validate using `FormDataConsumer` like this example with numbers instead of dates for more clarity:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  ArrayInput,
  Edit,
  FormTab,
  FormDataConsumer,
  NumberInput,
  SimpleFormIterator,
  TabbedForm
} from "react-admin";

const validateFromBeforeTo = (scopedFormData) => {
  return (value, allValues) => {
    console.log({ value, allValues, scopedFormData });
    const { to } = scopedFormData;
    const message =
      "error: date in field 'to' cant be before date in field 'from'";

    if (value - to > 0) {
      return message;
    }

    return undefined;
  };
};

const validateFifteenMin = () => {
  // anything
  return undefined;
};

const composeValidate = (scopedFormData) => [
  validateFifteenMin,
  validateFromBeforeTo(scopedFormData)
];

const PostEdit = (props) => {
  return (
    <Edit {...props}>
      <TabbedForm initialValues={{ availability: [{ from: 0, to: 0 }] }}>
        <FormTab>
          <ArrayInput source="availability">
            <SimpleFormIterator>
              <FormDataConsumer>
                {({ scopedFormData, getSource }) => (
                  <>
                    <NumberInput
                      label="Da"
                      source={getSource("from")}
                      validate={composeValidate(
                        scopedFormData
                      )}
                    />
                    <NumberInput label="A" source={getSource("to")} />
                  </>
                )}
              </FormDataConsumer>
            </SimpleFormIterator>
          </ArrayInput>
        </FormTab>
      </TabbedForm>
    </Edit>
  );
};

export default PostEdit;
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-kapitsa-20mgq?file=/src/posts/PostEdit.js:0-1579